# Problems With Creating a Fullscreen Mode Choosing Class

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe

I was trying to creating a class that allowed me to select whether I wanted a fullscreen window or a normal JFrame window where I choose the size. Here's the code:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame {

boolean fse = false;
int fsm = 0;
GraphicsDevice device = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()[1];

public Frame(String title, int width, int height) {
    setTitle(title);
    setSize(width, height);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);
}

private void checkFullscreenMode() {
    switch(fsm) {
    case 0:
        setUndecorated(false);
        System.out.println("No Fullscreen");
        break;
    case 1:
        setUndecorated(true);
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        break;
    case 2:
        setUndecorated(true);
        device.setFullScreenWindow(this);
        break;
    }
}

public void setFullscreenMode(int fsnm) {
    fse = true;
    if(fsm <= 2) {
        this.fsm = fsnm;
    }
    else {
        System.err.println("Error: Mode " + fsnm + " is not Supported!");
    }
}
```

}

When I tried calling the method setFullscreenMode, it wouldn't work. No matter what mode I chose it just gave me a 1280 x 720 frame. Here's how I called it:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame frame = new Frame("TheDlooter", 1280, 720);
        frame.setFullscreenMode(1);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that you are not calling `checkFullscreenMode()`. But actually this method making your frame full screen. So override the `setVisible` method in `Frame` and call `checkFullscreenMode()` in here.

Here is the working code:

```
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame frame = new Frame("TheDlooter");
        frame.setFullscreenMode(1);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Frame extends JFrame {

    boolean fse = false;
    int fsm = 0;
    GraphicsDevice device =
    GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()[1];

    public Frame(String title) {
        setTitle(title);

        add(new JLabel("ads"));

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void setVisible(boolean b) {
        checkFullscreenMode();
        super.setVisible(b);
    }

    public void checkFullscreenMode() {
        switch (fsm) {
        case 0:
            setUndecorated(false);
            System.out.println("No Fullscreen");
            break;
        case 1:
            setUndecorated(true);
            setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            break;
        case 2:
            setUndecorated(true);
            device.setFullScreenWindow(this);
            break;
        }
    }

    public void setFullscreenMode(int fsnm) {
        fse = true;
        if (fsm <= 2) {
            this.fsm = fsnm;
        } else {
            System.err.println("Error: Mode " + fsnm + " is not Supported!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't' work. Not having the two size parameters gives off an error.

Comment: Change constructor identifier to `public Frame(String title) {`.

Comment: I added constructor to my answer.

Comment: But then it creates a window with no size

Comment: I changed my answer. Please check it.